# Proxy not working with WBNB.withdraw and giving consistant error

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, bscscan

Here are:

- [the proxy contract](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x82fc944b314891cc7cbf99a04e6614ff420b6c4b)
- [the implementation contract](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x02fb76f0aff11c1b0789a93d8b403147c9edbc68)

And here are:

- [the transaction that failed](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x973ff3e3ea62f0f569e9888e93e2d9ea25072c5187afa1ba6e286d2065da0007)
- [the analysis of the failed transaction in Tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bsc-testnet/0x973ff3e3ea62f0f569e9888e93e2d9ea25072c5187afa1ba6e286d2065da0007)

As you can see, I call the swap method of the smart contract with a value of 1 BNB. This method:

1. receives 1 BNB.
2. deposits the 1 BNB into [the WBNB contract](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd). At this moment, 1 WBNB lies in the proxy.
3. withdraws the 1 WBNB. At this moment, 1 BNB lies in the proxy.
4. sends the 1 BNB back to the user.

The transaction seems to fail at the end of step 3.

Moreover, if I directly call the implementation contract, [it works](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x2aa0d19570135725a962e132d05282d9ff4a945ecc7ab8cdf4a86cdea587ee94).

So the issue seems to be coming specifically from the proxy. But after many hours of debugging, I have no idea why this fails… can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `withdraw` function of WBNB contract, it uses `transfer` to send BNB. With `transfer`, there is a fixed gas limit of 2300 gas, which is enough to complete the transfer operation, normally.

But when you call it behind a proxy, the proxy must perform an extra `SLOAD` operation to fetch the implementation address. The `SLOAD` has an increased price since [EIP1884](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1884), making the total price exceeds 2300, causing the transaction to fail.